# I have a strong pickle odor after installing laminate flooring

Tags: bathroom

After the installation of laminated flooring over tile floors in the bathroom I now have a strong pickle odor in the bathroom. They didn't let the leveling compound dry overnight. What can I do to get rid of the odor?

Comment: Did you unwrap the flooring at least 24hrs prior? I find that helps it off-gas.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's been over three weeks and still have a strong odor. I've been ventilating the room for three weeks. Idk what to do. Maybe if I  install the mouldings with silicone would help?

Answer (score 2):

Leveling compound dries very quickly. The fast setting stuff is dry in 1 to 2 hours.  HOWEVER...the smell can linger.  I always run the bath fan when pouring compound, and advise the homeowner to leave the fan on for about 4 hours.

The flooring can be giving off an odor also.
I believe if you run the bath fan the smell will dissipate in a day or so, possibly less.

Big question I have is why laminate in a bath!?

Comment: If they used the water proof stuff, it should be okay.  The water resistant will be iffy.